# Hibernate to persist Dates as long

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Is there a way to tell Hibernate that java.util.Date should be persisted as long? I need this to get around the missing millisecond resolution in MySQL.

Could you think of any drawbacks of this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a *virtual attribute*.

So you map a long, and add a get/set for a Date object. The setter sets the long value and the getter creates a new Date with the long.

And I can't see any drawbacks, only that probably you want to use a Date in your app (that's why I think the virtual attribute solution is goodish)

Comment: this approach doesn't play well with CriteriaQuery, which seems to ignore the getter/setter type and bind only to the long attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the field itself `long`. Or use a custom `UserType`. After implementing `UserType`, configure it on the field by `@Type(type = "com.yourcompany.YourUserType")`