# How to use a UserType to persist java.util.Date as LONG in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is a follow-up to the question [Hibernate to persist Dates as long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857926/hibernate-to-persist-dates-as-long)

One of the non-selected answers mentions the use of UserType.

How exactly can a UserType be used to cause java.util.Date to be persisted as a long?

Comment: Check this : https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/09/22/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/

Comment: @MouadELFakir CharacterType not relevant to this question